# HttpServletResponse How to get Header to check size

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-headers, http-post

I have a question about getting whole size of Response.

I was trying to use getHeader function to find the while size(byte) of headers but

I doesn't work to find whole size of header

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String

I am using doPost function and it passes request and response .

I was able to find contents of Request header however, i am not sure how to get the contents (or size) of Response

Does anyone know how to get byte size of response or contents of header  ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your servlet with a filter in two manners:

- Convert the response object to `org.apache.catalina.connector.Response`, and call 
  `getBytesWritten(false)`. This is what the access log valve does (see implementation [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.java)). Notice this is the size of the response body only.
- In the filter, Wrap the response with a caching response, that will cache the response body and headers. Then, after the request get the size. Again, this is the size of the response body only. You will have to construct the headers sizes yourself so expect some discrepancies.